# Fusion Tables query for grouped data timing out

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Using the guidelines [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_reference#Select) I have successfully queried a simple fusion table for some basic data with the following code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });

  function drawVisualization() {
        google.visualization.drawChart({
            containerId: 'visualization',
            dataSourceUrl: 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=',
            query: 'SELECT sector, revenue FROM 2961086',
            chartType: 'LineChart',
            options: {
                title: 'Net Revenue by Sector',
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'Revenue'
                },
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'Sector'
                }
            }
        });
  }

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

A problem arises when I attempt to aggregate the data by sector. I've tried the following

```
query: 'SELECT sector, revenue FROM 2961086 GROUP BY sector'
```

with no luck, the request eventually times out.

I threw together [two pages demonstrating the issue](http://morrisoncole.co.uk/fusiontest/linegraphnoagg.html).

I've also tried queries with various other parameters that work with no trouble whatsoever. Am I missing something?

Comment: Eric Bridger solved this. It turns out you must include an aggregate function in the query. For anyone wondering, here is the final solution to the example I posted earlier:

`query: 'SELECT sector, sum(revenue) FROM 2961086 GROUP BY sector'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a google.visualization user, just a fusion-table user but I would guess that you need an aggregate function in your query: SELECT sector, sum(revenue) from ... GROUP BY sector

Eric